# Error al intentar instalar SQLServer 2019/Could not load file or assembly 'System,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: sql-server, instalacion, assembly

El error se presenta después de realizar estos procesos de instalación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Después de esta pantalla me sale el siguiente error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor ayuda, no he logrado instalar SQLServer en este computador. :(

Comment: tienes instalado el framework 4 o posterior? revisa en la primera imagen (paso 1) selecciona todo para que no tengas ningún problema.

Comment: Hola Rangel, si señor ya tengo instalado framework 4, y acabo de hacer lo de seleccionar todo para instalar, sin embargo me sale el mismo error.